# Properties of the Majorization Order on $\mathbb{Z}^n$

Tags: reference-request, order-theory, lattice-orders

I'm looking for background material on the majorization (aka dominance) order over $\mathbb{Z}^n$ (rather than over partitions).

Let $v=(\psi_0,\dots,\psi_{n-1})$ and $u=(\phi_0,\dots,\phi_{n-1})$ be two elements in $\mathbb{Z}^n$. Then $u$ majorizes/dominates $v$ if and only if
$$\sum_{j=0}^i \psi_j\leq \sum_{j=0}^i \phi_j$$
for every $0\leq i \leq n-1$.

I'm interested in the covering relation of the poset, the rank function (it is a graded poset), distance function (corresponding to the covering relation/distance in the Hasse diagram) etc.

For some reason I couldn't find any reference specific to properties of this order over $\mathbb{Z}^n$, I hope I'm just missing something simple (maybe it's called differently over $\mathbb{Z}^n$ or something...).

Thanks

Comment: Can you describe the order please?

Comment: Added the relation definition, thanks.

Comment: Your poset is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z^n$ (with the order $u\leq v$ _iff_ for all $i$, $u_i\leq v_i$).

Comment: So $\phi$ covers $\psi$ _iff_ for all $i\neq i_0$, $\sum_{j=0}^i\phi_j=\sum_{j=0}^i\psi_j$ and $\sum_{j=0}^{i_0}\phi_j=1+\sum_{j=0}^{i_0}\psi_j$ for some $i_0\in\lbrace 0,\dots,n-1\rbrace$.

Comment: @OlivierBégassat I don't see why. $(3,1)$ dominates $(2,2)$ but not comparable in your relation.

Comment: _Isomorphic_, not equal! There is an obvious isomorphism given by $$\phi=(\phi_0,\dots,\phi_{n-1})\mapsto\left(\phi_0,\phi_0+\phi_1,\dots,\phi_0+ \cdots +\phi_{n-1}\right)$$

Comment: @OlivierBégassat Thanks Olivier, the cover condition seems to hold. How do you prove it?

Comment: You consider the cover relation on $\Bbb Z^n$ under the order I described, and you transpose it to majorization order via the isomorphism. You can also calculate the distance from that on $\Bbb Z^n$.

Comment: @OlivierBégassat Thanks Olivier, the isomorphism gave me everything I needed :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question, based on Olivier's comments:
$\mathbb{Z}^n$ with the dominance order is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^n$ with the point-wise $\leq$ order ($u\leq v$ iff $u_i\leq v_i$ for all $i$) through the isomorphism:
$$\varphi : (\phi_0,\dots,\phi_{n-1}) \mapsto (\phi_0,\phi_0+\phi_1,\dots,\phi_0+\dots+\phi_{n-1})$$
With:
$$\varphi^{-1} : (\phi_0,\dots,\phi_{n-1}) \mapsto (\phi_0,\phi_1-\phi_0,\phi_2-\phi_1,\dots,\phi_{n-1}-\phi_{n-2})$$

**Covering Relation**:
It's quite easy to see via $\varphi^{-1}$ that $\phi$ dominates $\psi$ iff $\phi_i = \psi_i +1$ and $\phi_{i+1} = \psi_{i+1} - 1$ for some $0\leq i\leq n-2$ or $\phi_{n-1} = \psi_{n-1} +1$ (and the rest are equal).

**Rank:**
$$rank(\psi_0,\dots,\psi_{n-1})=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\sum_{j=0}^{i}\psi_j$$

**Distance:**
Using modularity of the posets, the distance between two elements in the Hasse diagram is the difference between the ranks of their join and their meet that can be easily calculated.

Comment: Great! $+1{}{}{}$